# Filtering through Object for MultiCheckbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I have a multi checkbox for filtering objects and i am unable to handle the condition to return the necessary object based on a single condition for multiple options chosen from checkbox

I have written the condition using && operator and it looks for a exact match for the condition specified

```
let json = [{  
    "id": 1,
    "kba": false,
    "email": true
},
{   
    "id": 2,
    "kba": true,
    "email": true
},{
    "id": 3,
    "kba": true,
    "email": false
}]


function integrationFilter(selectedValue){
    return truthy = json.filter(j => {
        return j.kba === selectedValue.kba && j.email === selectedValue.email
    })
}

let selectedValue1 = {"email": false}
let t2 = {"kba": true}
let t3 = {"email": true, "kba": false}


let op = integrationFilter(t2)
console.log(op)
```

With my above logic, I get an empty array. But i would like to have the result since I am passing kba as true. They keys in the object represent the multiple choices I have and it might grow.

```
[ { id: 2, kba: true, email: true },
  { id: 3, kba: true, email: false } ]
```

Comment: So in case `selectedValue` is `{"email": true, "kba": true}` you want to get all objects which have *both* email true and kba true or *either* of them to be true?

Comment: I want to get all objects which have both {"email": true, "kba": true}

Comment: Ok, please see my answer. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking with `&&` which expects both the statement to `true`. I modified your filter function to handle your scenario.

```js
let json = [{
    "id": 1,
    "kba": false,
    "email": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "kba": true,
    "email": true
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "kba": true,
    "email": false
  }
]


function integrationFilter(selectedValue) {
  return json.filter(j => {
    return Object.entries(selectedValue).every(([key, value]) => {
      return j[key] === value;
    });
  });
}

let t1 = {
  "email": false
}
let t2 = {
  "kba": true
}
let t3 = {
  "email": true,
  "kba": false
}


console.log('t1:', integrationFilter(t1));
console.log('t2:', integrationFilter(t2));
console.log('t3:', integrationFilter(t3));
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understood, you want to match all keys provided in `selectedValue`. You can achieve it like this for example:

```js
let json = [{  
    "id": 1,
    "kba": false,
    "email": true
},
{   
    "id": 2,
    "kba": true,
    "email": true
},{
    "id": 3,
    "kba": true,
    "email": false
}]


function integrationFilter(selectedValue){
    const keysToValidate = Object.keys(selectedValue);
    return json.filter(j => {
        for (let key in selectedValue)
            if (j[key] !== selectedValue[key])
                return false;
        
        return true;
    })
}

let selectedValue1 = {"email": false}
let t2 = {"kba": true}
let t3 = {"email": true, "kba": false}


let op = integrationFilter(t2)
console.log(op)
```

Which selectes only values from `json` array which have all keys/values the same as `selectedValue`.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, Thanks the above solution posted by ajai works. In your solution, it returns the object with ids 2 and 3 whereas it should just return the id 1

Comment: I believe the results are just the same. I posted only one example which is exactly the same as above solution